# Fibrant morphisms are stable under pullbacks in the category of congruences

Tags: category-theory

I'm struggling to see why fibrant morphisms are stable under pullbacks in the category of congruences of a category. That is given a pullback:

[image]

such that $(\tilde f', f')$ is fibrant, $(\tilde f,f)$ is fibrant as well.

I  *think* that the above being a pullback implies that $(a,f',f,b)$ is a pullback too and I thought I could use this together with the pullback lemma. However this idea only seems to work  if $(\tilde a, \tilde f', \tilde f, \tilde b)$ is a pullback too, and I don't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fibrant morphisms are stable under pullbacks *in the category of congruences*. These pullbacks are computed "degreewise", in the sense that *both* squares you mention are pullbacks$^*$. So your argument with the pullback lemma is the correct way to prove this result.

---

$*$ In fact, all limits in the category of congruences can be obtained this way (assuming the ambient category has limits). Here's one way to see it. Let us call $\mathcal{C}$ the ambient category, and consider the categories $\mathbf{RG}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\mathbf{Con}(\mathcal{C})$ of [internal reflexive graphs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive%20graph) (or quivers) and congruences in $\mathcal{C}$. Then $\mathbf{RG}(\mathcal{C})$ can be identified with the functor category $[A,\mathcal{C}]$, where $A$ is the "walking reflexive graph", i.e. the category with two objects $A_1,A_0$ and three non-identity arrows $s,t:A_1\to A_0$ and $e:A_0\to A_1$ satisfying $se=1_{A_0}=te$. In particular, it has limits, and these are computed separately at the level of the "object of edges" and "object of vertices".

Now $\mathbf{Con}(\mathcal{C})$ is a full subcategory of $\mathbf{RG}(\mathcal{C})$, and it is closed under limits in $\mathbf{RG}(\mathcal{C})$; thus it has all limits, and they can be computed as in $\mathbf{RG}(\mathcal{C})$, i.e. separately at each object.

To prove that $\mathbf{Con}(\mathcal{C})$ is closed under limits, note that the conditions on a reflexive graphs to be a congruence (the two arrows being jointly monic, symmetry, transitivity) can all be expressed with commutative diagrams and limits; thus they are preserved by functors which preserve limits. Now taking limits is itself a functor that preserve limits (because limits commute with limits).

Alternatively, since the Yoneda embedding is a functor that preserves limits, and since, again, limits in functor categories are computed pointwise, you can actually simply check that it holds in the category of sets. This is an application of a meta-theorem about statements involving diagrams and limits; you can find more details in the "Preliminaries" section of [these notes](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~tholen/HB07BournClementino.pdf) (and also at the beginning of Borceux-Bourn, I think).

Comment: Oh okay. Then my question is "why is the second square a pullback?". I have trouble seeing this. After that it is obvious.

Comment: That's how pullbacks are computed in the category of congruences. Basically, you take the two pullbacks, and you have induced arrows that form a reflexive graph between the two. Then you can prove that it is actually a relation, and in fact a congruence.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it again tomorrow. - For the record, I have not even proved that the category of congruences has pullbacks, hence the 'being in the dark'. Do you happen to know any references on the matter? ("Categorical Foundations" Chapter IV does not say anything about that afaik).

Comment: I've expanded my answer to explain a bit more how limits in the category of congruences work (and why). I don't think I have any reference to give you about this, sorry.